# Error build Angular by library ng-multiselect-dropdown

Tags: angular

from now, thank you for you help.
I am in need of help with my Angular project. I am wanting to do a build, so I can upload it to my server, but when I run the command I get this error.

[image]

My version angular-cli

[image]

My package.json

```
{
  "name": "gestion-equipos-frontend",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/cdk": "^8.2.3",
    "@angular/common": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/core": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/http": "^7.2.16",
    "@angular/material": "^8.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/router": "~8.1.2",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^5.3.0",
    "@ng-select/ng-select": "^3.7.2",
    "@schematics/angular": "^8.3.25",
    "@syncfusion/ej2": "^17.4.50",
    "@syncfusion/ej2-angular-dropdowns": "^17.4.50",
    "chart.js": "^2.9.3",
    "chartjs-plugin-annotation": "^0.5.7",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "ng-multiselect-dropdown": "^0.2.10",
    "ng2-charts": "^2.3.0",
    "ngx-pagination": "^4.1.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.4.0",
    "sweetalert2": "^8.19.0",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.801.3",
    "@angular/cli": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/language-service": "~8.1.2",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.8",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.3.32",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "^5.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.2",
    "protractor": "^5.4.3",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.15.0",
    "typescript": "~3.4.3"
  }
}
```

I tried to change the version of ng-multiselect-dropdown, but it does not work.

```
Date: 2020-04-20T17:35:10.624Z - Hash: b4f0ca043a73da9dd0b4
1 unchanged chunks
chunk {0} runtime.ddc91d8bbbefe07a25ea.js, runtime.ddc91d8bbbefe07a25ea.js.map (runtime) 1.46 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {1} main.f1be7b5afedf7cad754c.js, main.f1be7b5afedf7cad754c.js.map (main) 1.8 MB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {2} polyfills.f9be0135f9d2eb97d281.js, polyfills.f9be0135f9d2eb97d281.js.map (polyfills) 36.3 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {3} styles.180ffb55b74a9cc004de.css, styles.180ffb55b74a9cc004de.css.map (styles) 66.1 kB [initial] [rendered]
Time: 55820ms

ERROR in src/app/components/equipo/equipo.component.ts:25:35 - error TS2307: Cannot find module 'ng-multiselect-dropdown'.

25 import { IDropdownSettings } from 'ng-multiselect-dropdown';
                                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/app/components/usuario/usuario.component.ts:15:35 - error TS2307: Cannot find module 'ng-multiselect-dropdown'.

15 import { IDropdownSettings } from 'ng-multiselect-dropdown';
                                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/app/app.module.ts:44:45 - error TS2307: Cannot find module 'ng-multiselect-dropdown'.

44 import { NgMultiSelectDropDownModule } from 'ng-multiselect-dropdown';
                                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

ERROR in ./node_modules/ng-multiselect-dropdown/fesm2015/ng-multiselect-dropdown.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/src/build-optimizer/webpack-loader.js):
TypeError: Cannot read property 'kind' of undefined
    at isAngularDecoratorMetadataExpression (C:\Users\lbrizuela\GestionEquiposFrontend\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\src\transforms\scrub-file.js:265:35)
    at checkNodeForDecorators (C:\Users\lbrizuela\GestionEquiposFrontend\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\src\transforms\scrub-file.js:77:21)
    at visitNodes (C:\Users\lbrizuela\GestionEquiposFrontend\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:16514:30)
    at Object.forEachChild (C:\Users\lbrizuela\GestionEquiposFrontend\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:16740:24)
    at checkNodeForDecorators (C:\Users\lbrizuela\GestionEquiposFrontend\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\src\transforms\scrub-file.js:68:31)
    at visitNode (C:\Users\lbrizuela\GestionEquiposFrontend\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:16505:24)
    at Object.forEachChild (C:\Users\lbrizuela\GestionEquiposFrontend\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:16635:21)
    at checkNodeForDecorators (C:\Users\lbrizuela\GestionEquiposFrontend\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\src\transforms\scrub-file.js:68:31)
    at visitNode (C:\Users\lbrizuela\GestionEquiposFrontend\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:16505:24)
    at Object.forEachChild (C:\Users\lbrizuela\GestionEquiposFrontend\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:16703:24)
    at checkNodeForDecorators (C:\Users\lbrizuela\GestionEquiposFrontend\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\src\transforms\scrub-file.js:68:31)
    at visitNode (C:\Users\lbrizuela\GestionEquiposFrontend\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:16505:24)
    at Object.forEachChild (C:\Users\lbrizuela\GestionEquiposFrontend\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:16692:24)
    at checkNodeForDecorators (C:\Users\lbrizuela\GestionEquiposFrontend\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\src\transforms\scrub-file.js:68:31)
    at visitNode (C:\Users\lbrizuela\GestionEquiposFrontend\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:16505:24)
    at Object.forEachChild (C:\Users\lbrizuela\GestionEquiposFrontend\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:16599:21)
ERROR in src/app/app.module.ts(113,5): Error during template compile of 'AppModule'
  Could not resolve ng-multiselect-dropdown relative to [object Object]..
src/app/app.module.ts(113,5): Error during template compile of 'AppModule'
  Could not resolve ng-multiselect-dropdown relative to [object Object]..
: Can't bind to 'placeholder' since it isn't a known property of 'ng-multiselect-dropdown'.
1. If 'placeholder' is an Angular directive, then add 'CommonModule' to the '@NgModule.imports' of this component.
2. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("s="box-info col-md-12 mt-4" *ngIf="vendedoresLoaded">
                    <ng-multiselect-dropdown [ERROR ->][placeholder]="'Vendedores'" [data]="dropdownList" [(ngModel)]="selectedItems" [settings]="dropdownSe")
: Can't bind to 'data' since it isn't a known property of 'ng-multiselect-dropdown'.
1. If 'data' is an Angular directive, then add 'CommonModule' to the '@NgModule.imports' of this component.
2. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("ngIf="vendedoresLoaded">
                    <ng-multiselect-dropdown [placeholder]="'Vendedores'" [ERROR ->][data]="dropdownList" [(ngModel)]="selectedItems" [settings]="dropdownSettings" (onSelect)="onItemSel")
: Can't bind to 'settings' since it isn't a known property of 'ng-multiselect-dropdown'.
1. If 'settings' is an Angular directive, then add 'CommonModule' to the '@NgModule.imports' of this component.
2. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("multiselect-dropdown [placeholder]="'Vendedores'" [data]="dropdownList" [(ngModel)]="selectedItems" [ERROR ->][settings]="dropdownSettings" (onSelect)="onItemSelect($event)" (onSelectAll)="onSelectAll($event)" n")
: 'ng-multiselect-dropdown' is not a known element:
1. If 'ng-multiselect-dropdown' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'ng-multiselect-dropdown' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("                <div class="box-info col-md-12 mt-4" *ngIf="vendedoresLoaded">
                    [ERROR ->]<ng-multiselect-dropdown [placeholder]="'Vendedores'" [data]="dropdownList" [(ngModel)]="selectedItem")
```

Thank you.